# Query speed and expressions with constant value

Tags: sql

Is

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID=2*2
```

slower than

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID=4
```

I mean:  is **2*2** calculated once or is it calculated when checking each record?

You may ask why write 2*2 and not just simply 4?

Well actually in my real case I have some numbers which represents characters building some text (somebody had a "great" idea of saving array of numeric data as string).

So my query would be like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table where value1=(CHAR(20)+CHAR(8)+CHAR(32))
```

I could calculate this string on my side but there could be possible problems with encoding, passing characters like `/n` or `/r` in a query etc.

Will this `(CHAR(20)+CHAR(8)+CHAR(32))` slow my query if I use it instead of plain string text like '#!_'

Answer (score 3):

it will be the same performance with a constant expression like 2*2. However if you start comparing ID/2 = 2. It will slow down the query because it has to calculate for all rows.

Comment: Agree with this, the performance id different only if you perform a calculation on each row. In your example the SQL engine receives 4 and not 2*2.